# Custom post type child of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to make a custom post type as child of another CPT.

or

Add a taxonomy for ID of parent post (then how to make it required).

**Why I am doin this ?**

Actually I have two custom post type `user_projects` and `user_child_projects`, both are post not page.

`user_child_projects` are child of `user_projects`, `user_child_projects` must have a valid `user_projects` ID.

Please help me, I am trying to do this from past five days

Comment: Can you explain why you need these to be two separate post types? Would be easier to just use just one type and choose the parent project as per normal.

Comment: Just found on google, that this feature was requested on wordpress.. POST to POST relationship.. no easy way found

Comment: Maybe this plugin is helpful in your case: http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Comment: I have solved this problem, and believe me its was much easier then using that plugin.